# Why does MATLAB live script not work when I switch my internet connection?

Tags: matlab

**Problem**

I recently downloaded and started using the free version of MATLAB (it is free for the duration of the machine learning course).
Everything was working fine until today when I saw that when I switch to a different internet connection (other than my home wifi), the MATLAB live script editor fails to load.
What exactly happens is, it shows a "loading" screen on the live editor window and nothing happens after that. All the other features however remain intact and work fine.

*This thing is for sure as I tested it many times by disconnecting from the internet, using MATLAB in offline mode, connecting back to the home-wifi, restarting my computer etc.*

*Funny thing is, everything seems to work when MATLAB is in offline mode or connected to home-wifi, but the problem seems to happen when I connect to a different network.*

**Here are some changes that I made to my computer yesterday which may have affected the MATLAB software in some way (but I highly doubt it!)**

- changed the default path to a new path.
- installed Octave (version 4.0).

Here are some things which readers of this question might find useful :

- *OS : Mac OS X Sierra*
- *MATLAB Version : R2017b (free for online course, Coursera)*
- *The other internet connection I use (the one with which MATLAB is having issues with) doesn't have any problem because I use it to connect to Steam, App Store, browse the internet etc. and everything works fine.*

**P.S. This is just an after thought, could it be because of some port issues? (I do not know much about ports and proxies and stuff!)**

**Update :**
*I have unchecked the option 'send reports to Matlab' because I reasoned, maybe it is establishing a connection to their servers and sending usage info/statistics/analysis etc but still it did not solve the problem*

Comment: I don't see why livescript needs internet connection to start with. Does it work when you're offline?

Comment: Yes, it does work when I am offline. But I would really like it to work no matter what network I am connected to.

Comment: It may be useful to report this problem to MATLAB.

Comment: Ohh! So it means it's a bug? I was under the impression that I had messed up with the system.